# Color issue - Previews in Bridge are way different than outputted PDF

Tags: color, adobe-bridge

I am generally able to modify files xmp data for white balance/exposure, then output from bridge as a contact sheet without any issues. I've switched to a different MacPro and upgraded to Mountain Lion - And now my outputs are way different than the preview within Bridge. I've had similar issues when saving out jpgs from photoshop. Ideas???!?

[img http://elijahhoffman.com/files/colorissue.png](http://elijahhoffman.com/files/colorissue.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you converting the files to srgb first? Check in bridge preferences > output to see if preserve color profiles is checked.